# File downloaded but size is different

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL script to download a file, but the size of the file downloaded is not the same as the server size:

Download window pop-up message:

```
Document (389 bytes)
```

But the file is MP3 and given Document.

On my computer, when I check the file info, it is given:

```
Kind: MP3 audio 
Size: 389 bytes (4 KB on disk)
```

The code is

```
$url = strip_tags($_GET['path']);

//echo $url.'<br>';

$fileName = strip_tags($_GET['file']);

//echo $fileName;

set_time_limit(0);

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: filename=$fileName");


set_time_limit(0);
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url.$fileName));//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

The command line to check the file size on the server:

```
419036 Mar 24  2014 001.mp3
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Here you go: http://www.alfirdaous.com/Downloads/Medias/Sawtiyat/Quoran/TilawatSheikhs/AhmadAlObaid/11/MP3/alfirdaous.com_AhmadAlObaid_HafsAnAssim_001.mp3

Comment: Chances are that the file you store contains an error message instead of the audio. Put a `echo file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp');` at the end of the script and see what you get.

Comment: the echo has given a blank result

Comment: OK, do it with a `var_dump` instead of `echo`. You should try harder to see what those 389 bytes are Or if you have access to the server, just open the file in a simple text editor, and see  what is in it. You could rename it to *.txt if that helps to see it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Also make sure www user has enough permission to write on the directory. You have used wrong HTTP hoarders for curl. That's why download failed.

```
<?php

$url = strip_tags($_GET['path']);

//echo $url.'<br>';

$fileName = strip_tags($_GET['file']);

//echo $fileName;

set_time_limit(0);

$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/localfile.tmp', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
$url = str_replace(" ","%20",$url.$fileName);

$ch = curl_init($url);//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Host   www.alfirdaous.com',
    'User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0',
    'Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language    en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate',
    'Connection keep-alive',
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: It is the same result, the file is downloaded has the same size